# How to show the latest sites added to bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

How to show the latest sites added to bookmarks in Chrome?

I want to know this because I am looking for one site that I recently added to the bookmarks but forgot where I put into (different folders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an area Chrome does not do by default (although I could be mistaken)

I know you can get an extension from  [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recent-bookmarks/olndffocioplakeilhkgenfgdincjlpn?hl=en) which will do what you want. I have not personally used this extension so I don't know if it will backdate based on the bookmarks you have, but I don't see why it wouldn't.

Do let me know if it does should you happen to try it.

Comment: Good stuff :) might want to mark the question as answered so others don't get involved.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it without extension. Go to Bookmarks manager, and on the bottom you have  Recent, click there and you will have it sorted top to bottom.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see the `Recent` to click. Any idea?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95714?hl=en It's located on the left, below the folders that are created, it has yellow star in front of it!

Comment: here is image http://postimg.org/image/4shqa4p5h/

Comment: Thanks for help. But it has been removed in the new version Chrome (e.g. in Version 31.0.1650.63 m).

Comment: I have an old one then :))